# How can I use the Google Places API to handle both search requests with and without a location?

Tags: google-places-api

So, maps.google.com allows you to search for "sushi bar" by itself, and have it search in the current map location. You can also search for "sushi bar in New York, NY" and it will ignore the current map and search New York City.

How can I use the Google Places API to have both of these work in a single search field? It seems like both nearby and text search allows for an optional location, but I don't know how to use it with the input text being "sushi bar in New York, NY."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text Search does allow for an optional location. You may not need it if you are including the city in a Text Search (which is 10x more expensive than a Nearby Search, so if you know a lat/long, use that instead)

However according to the API documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests) you would format a text search like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?location=40.7117,-74.0125&query=sushi+bar+in+New+York,+NY&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere